# Seaborn plotting annotations in bar charts horizontal

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataframe like so:

```
switch_summary                             duration   count
McDonalds -> Arbys -> McDonalds            0.067      1
Wendys -> Popeyes -> McDonalds -> KFC      0.293      1
Arbys -> Wendys -> Popeyes -> McDonalds    0.542      2
Arbys -> McDonalds -> KFC                  1.075      1
KFC -> Arbys -> Wendys -> Popeyes          2.123      3
KFC -> Wendys -> Popeyes -> Arbys          2.297      1
```

I want to create a seaborn plot to visualize both the duration and the count.

I have the following code:

```
plt.figure(figsize = [15,7])
ax = (sns.barplot(x = 'duration',
                  y = 'switch_summary',
                  palette = sns.color_palette('winter', 10),
                  data = df))

for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    plt.text( 0.1 + p.get_width(), p.get_y() + 0.55 * p.get_height(),
            '~{:1.2f}\n days'.format(width),
            ha = 'center', va = 'center', color = 'black', weight = 'bold')

ax = ax.set(title = 'Top 10 Fastest Trends',
            xlabel = 'Total Duration in Trend',
            ylabel = 'Restaurant Trend')
```

This code will display the duration but I also want to display the count.

How can I display the count in the `plt.text()` portion of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick workaround will be to enumerate the patches, get the count using the index.

```
import pandas as pd  
  
data = {'switch_summary': ['McDonalds -> Arbys -> McDonalds ', 'Wendys -> Popeyes -> McDonalds -> KFC', 'Arbys -> Wendys -> Popeyes -> McDonalds ', 'Arbys -> McDonalds -> KFC', 'KFC -> Arbys -> Wendys -> Popeyes', 'KFC -> Wendys -> Popeyes -> Arbys '], 
        'duration': [0.067, 0.293,  0.542, 1.075, 2.123, 2.297],
        'count': [1, 1, 2,1,3,1]
       }  
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

plt.figure(figsize = [15,7])
ax = (sns.barplot(x = 'duration',
                  y = 'switch_summary',
                  palette = sns.color_palette('winter', 10),
                  data = df))

for i,p in enumerate(ax.patches):
    width = p.get_width()
    plt.text( 0.1 + p.get_width(), p.get_y() + 0.55 * p.get_height(),
            '~{:1.2f}\n days \n count - {}'.format(width,df['count'][i]),
            ha = 'center', va = 'center', color = 'black', weight = 'bold')

ax = ax.set(title = 'Top 10 Fastest Trends',
            xlabel = 'Total Duration in Trend',
            ylabel = 'Restaurant Trend')
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Please don't assign `ax = ax.set(...)` as `ax.set()` doesn't return an `ax`.